# Is there an easy way to run Azure DevOps PowerShell scripts on my local machine?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I tried to find anything on this but I didn't succeed. Maybe I am using the wrong words for the search.

What I am trying to achieve is that I have a script that can run in an Azure DevOps environment as well as on my local machine for debug purposes. As far as I can see to execute locally I would need some kind of wrapper for the script that is behaving like the Azure DevOps Task is. Does anything like that exist out there?

Comment: Depends, I assume you are using azure specific variables in the script? You could pass them as parameters. You should include the script in your question.

Comment: My problem mainly is the usage of e.g. $(SomeVariable) and environment variables. I'll try to come up with a small sample script to make it easier to grasp.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have more control over building your code and be able to see intermediate results you need to install self-hosted agent on your machine. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) you have more info about this.

Most of the task are simply wrappers around console tools which adds sort of authorization or making them visually accessible. Maybe useful for you will be enable [System.Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug) flag on Microsoft agent to see more details what particular task does. You will see more details and thus be able to better understand what is happening behind.

For instance if you use variables in your script like `$(someVariable)` setting `System.Debug` you will see your final script in the log with replaced values.

Be aware also that Secret variables are masked. So you may find `***` in logs instead of real value.

However, there is no easy way just to extract and wrap what task does to repeat it on your machine without involving Azure DevOps agent.